# git reset --soft strange behavior

Tags: git, version-control, git-reset

I wanted to squash 3 commits, before I push into the `develop` branch in the remote repository. I thought I'll use `git reset --soft HEAD~3` (to remove my last 3 commits and make them in a single commit with a new commit message). However, when I wrote the command, I noticd that it didn't reset only 3 commits, but like 20 (don't worry, I had backup). After that, I thought I'd try again with previous commits (just to test the behavior), and I saw that it wasn't only deleting 3 commits, but a random number.

What could this be from? (Note: The "HEAD~3" commit had merge conflicts when pulling before that, that were solved by me, not sure if that could be the case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reset a **merge** commit, then you will remove all the commits that were merged into your branch...

Suppose you had another branch with 10 commits, which you merge into your `develop` branch. If you run now `git reset --soft HEAD~1`, then you will see all changes from these 10 commits.

## more in-depth explanation

Suppose you have the following commits:

```
abc123 last commit (HEAD)
def456 merge feature2-branch (with 10 commits)
ghi789 add feature
jkl123 fix bug
```

HEAD (where you are in your history) is at `abc123`. When you execute now the command `git reset --soft HEAD~3`,

- this does **NOT** mean: `git`, please remove the last 3 commits.
- this **does** mean: `git`, please move `HEAD` to `jkl123`, but leave all files as they are.

So `git` does not have a notion of a number of commits, nor whether they are merge commits or whatever.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? Is there any way to avoid this behavior? Something like a flag that you pass to the git reset? Since you can easily rewrite commits that are not made by you. How does git know if it is a normal commit or a merge commit?

Comment: No there is not even a theoretical way in which this would work. By merging you include all that work, if you undo the merge commit but keep the work, then of course you have all the work from that branch. What different behavior could you expect?

Comment: Something like a warning: are you sure? (like when they want you to add a force flag, so you don't accidentally delete something)

Comment: @jhon354 I just edited my answer. I hope you understand better how `git` works now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you merged into your branch then then run reset.

Here's a plan that could work.

1. On your branch find the commit before you merged.
2. `git checkout last_commit_before_merge`
3. `git branch -b feature/_X_attempt2`
4. Do you squashing - I recommend `git rebase --interactive`
5. Follow your usual flow: merge master, push, create PR

---

After you rewind to your branch before the merge you can just rebase master on your branch with `git rebase -i master`. See [Merging vs. Rebasing](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing).

---

Note: This is all in the context that you don't share branches with others because rebasing (as well as your `git reset` method) rewrites history.